# Databinding to a method in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, methods

I am having trouble databinding a `TextBox.Text` property to a object's method. The idea is allowing the user to write in a `TextBox` a file name and then have a `TextBlock` output that file's extension.

```
class GetFileInfo
{
    public string GetFileExtension(string fileName)
    {
        return Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="getFileInfo" MethodName="GetFileExtension" ObjectType="{x:Type local:GetFileInfo}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <sys:String>abc.text</sys:String>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="textBox1">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource getFileInfo}" Path="MethodParameters[0]" BindsDirectlyToSource="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource getFileInfo}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

For some reason it is not doing anything. Anyknow could point out what may be the reasons?
Here is what I see on the designer and when I run the application:

[image]

And here is what happens when I try setting other text at run-time:

[image]

Here is the error given by de debugger when trying to set other text at run-time:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=MethodParameters[0]; DataItem='ObjectDataProvider' (HashCode=2207369); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='textBox1'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') ArgumentException:'System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker+IListIndexerArg' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32'.
>      at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
>      at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.SetValue(Object item, Object value)
>      at MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.UpdateValue(Object value)
>      at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(Object value)'

Comment: You have to change the idea from binding Method to property. and learn the concept of INotifyPropertyChanged & DataContext. Google some MVVM pattern too.

Comment: +1 for asking a question that will help a lot of people that don't understand databinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems like this a bug when running WPF 4.0, as can be seen in comments [here](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=22).

> Woops, I was a bit hasty .. the example works perfectly as long you compile it for the 3.5 framework (in VS 2010).
>   But if you convert it to WPF 4.0 project the method WeightOnPlanet on ObjectDataProvider is nolonger invoked on odp2 when you edit the textbox.
>   I have tried to find any new Attributes on either the Binding or the ObjectDataProvider – but nothing has worked out so far …

When compiling in 3.5, it works fine here.

Answer (score 7):

While it's possible to use `Binding` to call a method and get its return value, it's not straightforward.  It's *much* simpler to bind to properties, and to use the combination of binding and change notification to get the result you're looking for.

Create a class with two properties, `Filename` and `Extension`.  `Filename` is just a read/write string property.  `Extension` is a read-only string property whose getter calls the method that you're trying to call.

Now make that class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because if a property can change in code, it needs a way of telling the binding that it has done so.  Make the setter of the `Filename` property notify bindings that the `Extension` property has changed.

Add a `Binding` to a `TextBox` that binds to the `Filename` property using the `TwoWay` mode.  Add a `Binding` to a `TextBox` that binds to `Extension` using the default `OneWay` mode.

The sequence of events is:

1. User types a new `Filename` into a bound `TextBox` and presses TAB.
2. The `TextBox` loses focus.
3. Because the `Binding`'s mode is `TwoWay`, and it's using the default behavior of updating the source when the target loses focus, that's what it does.
4. The `Binding` updates the source by calling the `Filename` setter.
5. The `Filename` setter raises `PropertyChanged`.
6. The `Binding` handles `PropertyChanged`, looks at its argument, and sees that the `Extension` property has changed.
7. The `Binding` calls the `Extension` property's getter.
8. The `Extension` property's getter calls the method to determine the extension for `Filename`, and returns it to the `Binding`.
9. The `Binding` updates its target `TextBox` with the new value of `Extension`.

This is the core concept underlying data binding and the MVVM pattern.  Once you understand it, it becomes second nature, and WPF development becomes about ten million times easier.

Comment: I'm using Sam's Teach Yourself WPF in 24 hours ebook and ive learned tons so far and im ony on chapter 6 (the databinding chapter) by far one of the easiest ways to learn WPF. I spent hours looking for resources online and this book is by far the best ive found for WPF beginners. :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to get an understanding of MVVM , check this classic article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: Yes, but as pointed in my post, the idea is to type what you want in the textbox at run-time. I know that it is doing what he should with the string I'm giving him at design time inside the <string> tags.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding requires the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event to be called when the source is updated. In this case, you'd want to wrap this function call in a get/set like so:

```
public class FileWrapper: System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged{
    private string m_filename;

    public string FileExtension{
        get{ return GetFileExtension(FileName);}
    }

    public string FileName{
        get{ return m_filename;}
        set{ m_filename = value; OnPropertyChanged("FileName"); OnPropertyChanged( "FileExtension");
    }

    public string GetFileExtension( string filename){
        //implementation
    }

    public event System.ComponentModel.NotifyPropertyChangedEvent PropertyChanged = (a,b)=>{};

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string property){
        PropertyChanged( this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs( property ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try this code. But isn't there a simpler solution to just run some method from a given class given some parameters?

Comment: @devoured, If you prefer to do in in proper WPF way, this should be the code you need to use. There is nothing crazy going on in the above code, if you learn this it is gonna help you forever with WPF. in any MVVM based WPF you can see this small piece of code snippet. So it worth a learning.

Comment: But where should this be put? Should FileExtension be a Window's property?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `DataContext` set?  In your code-behind, did you set the value for your `TextBlock` to "saadsas" (I can only guess), which broke your databinding?

Comment: I edited my original post. Basically everything I wrote in my code files is there. I didn't set a DataContext. In fact, im googling right now what a DataContext is.