# Binding 'Enabled' property of a Button to DataSet.HasChanges()

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I want to bind the [`Enabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.enabled.aspx) property of a `Button` on my C# Windows Forms application to whether an instance `DataSet` variable has changes.  (I.e. if the `DataSet` is unchanged, disable the save button.)

The trouble is, [`DataSet.HasChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zky7370c.aspx) is implemented as a *method*, not as a property, so it cannot be bound to.  Is there any easy way to implement this?  Am I approaching this the wrong way?  It seems like something like this would be much easier than disabling and enabling the button manually wherever the data changes.

In my research I came up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305203/databinding-to-a-method-in-wpf), but its solution (designing classes such that what you need to bind to is a property) seems impractical for this situation.

Comment: You could just enable the button all the time, then check in the event handler for changes in your dataset (maybe have it display a MessageBox or do nothing if there aren't any?) just an alternative way of doing it.

Comment: It would work, but it seems like it would look unprofessional.  I would much rather disable the button if there's nothing to save.  If I can't get this way working, though, I may just have to use your idea.

Comment: You can add a view model that represents HasChanges as a property.

Comment: This is in a WinForms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a WinForms application you don't need to bind the Enabled property of the button directly to the DataSet at all. Build an intermediary layer (this will be easier to maintain and expand on later anyway), with a class that interprets the method of the DataSet into a Property that the control can bind to:

```
public bool HasChanges
{
    get
    {
        return myData == null ? false : this.myData.HasChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: This really wouldn't work.  If the DataSet changes, this property won't get automatically updated and the user's button's enabled property won't change.

Comment: All he needs to do is notify the UI that this property has changed, in the same way that you notify that any property has changed, when the dataset is updated.

Comment: I ended up finding an alternative way to structure my program so this wasn't necessary, but this does basically answer the question, so I'll accept it.